# MS Excel VB export data to text file

Tags: vba, excel

Is there a way using Excel macros in Windows to:

1. Create `.txt` file name using value or content of a cell say `A1`. It could be alphanumeric.
2. Then get Excel data from range column B, where the rows count varies. Should get only data not empty rows of column B.
3. Save the text file on desktop, show message of exact location of file saved.
4. Now as its saved, if macro is run again with same text file name, should replace the previous file if its name is same.
5. The macro is run from another sheet in same workbook, not from the sheet which contains data. Say Macro is from `sheet1` and data is in `sheet2`, the data contains quotes singe or double and pipe, which should not be affected on export.
6. And the clipboard should be cleared after export, as in this code.

Please suggest.

```
Sub Export() 
    Dim rc As Variant 
    Dim s As String 

    s = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\Hello World.txt" 
    Range("B:B").Copy 

    MakeTXTFile s 

    rc = Shell("notepad " & s, 1) 
    Kill s 
End Sub 

Sub MakeTXTFile(filePath As String, str As String) 
    Dim hFile As Integer 
    If Dir(FolderPart(filePath), vbDirectory) = "" Then 
        MsgBox filePath, vbCritical, "Missing Folder" 
        Exit Sub 
    End If 

    hFile = FreeFile 
    Open filePath For Output As #hFile 
    If str <> "" Then Print #hFile, str 
    Close hFile 
End Sub 

Function FolderPart(sPath As String) As String 
    FolderPart = Left(sPath, InStrRev(sPath, "\")) 
End Function 


Function getClipboard() 
     'Add Reference:   'Reference: Microsoft Forms xx Object
    Dim MyData As DataObject 

    On Error Resume Next 
    Set MyData = New DataObject 
    MyData.GetFromClipboard 
    getClipboard = MyData.GetText 
End Functionb
```

I used above code.

Answer (score 0):

The code shall be something like that:

```
Sub Export()
Dim rc As Variant
Dim s As String
Dim fso As Object
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim oFile As Object

If (ActiveSheet.Name <> "Sheet1") Then
    MsgBox ("Error: Wrong Sheet")
    Exit Sub
End If

s = MyDocs & "\" & Range("A1").Value & ".txt"
Set oFile = fso.CreateTextFile(s)

For Each xx In Range("B:B")
    If xx.Value <> "" Then oFile.WriteLine xx
Next
oFile.Close
Set fso = Nothing
Set oFile = Nothing

MsgBox ("Saved in: " & s)

rc = Shell("notepad " & s, 1)
'    Kill s
End Sub
```

It's not clear the point 6. I put a check, inside you can put what you want...
In this code there isn't check for the filename
Try to use the OLD method...

```
Dim rc As Variant
Dim s As String
Dim xx

If (ActiveSheet.Name <> "Sheet1") Then
    MsgBox ("Error: Wrong Sheet")
    Exit Sub
End If

s = MyDocs & "\" & Range("A1").Value & ".txt"
Open s For Output As #1
For Each xx In Range("B:B")
    If xx.Value <> "" Then Print #1, xx
Next
Close #1

MsgBox ("Saved in: " & s)
rc = Shell("notepad " & s, 1)
```

Comment: the code is failing with the following error 

Run-time error-2147023582(80070522):

Method CreateTextFIle of object IFileSystem3 failed

Comment: You have the reference 'Microsoft Scripting Runtime' loaded ?

Comment: i don't think we use that